# behavior when for-loop variable overflow and compiler optimization

Tags: c

While reading http://blog.llvm.org/2011/05/what-every-c-programmer-should-know.html about undefined behavior in c, I get a question on this example.

```
for (i = 0; i <= N; ++i) { ... }
```

> In this loop, the compiler can assume that the loop will iterate
> exactly N+1 times if "i" is undefined on overflow, which allows a
> broad range of loop optimizations to kick in. On the other hand, if
> the variable is defined to wrap around on overflow, then the compiler
> must assume that the loop is possibly infinite (which happens if N is
> INT_MAX) - which then disables these important loop optimizations.
> This particularly affects 64-bit platforms since so much code uses
> "int" as induction variables.

This example is to show the C compiler could take advantage of the undefined behavior to make assumption that the execution times would be exact N+1. But I don't understand why this assumption is valid.

I can understand that if the variable is defined to wrap around on overflow and N is INT_MAX, then the for loop will be infinite because i will go from 0 to INT_MAX and overflow to  INT_MIN, then loop to INT_MAX and restart from INT_MIN etc. So the compiler could not make this assumption about execution times and can not do optimization on this point.

But what about when i is undefined on overflow?  In this case, i loops normally from 0 to INT_MAX, then i will be assigned `INT_MAX+1`, which would overflow to an undefined value such as between 0 and INT_MAX. If so, the condition `i<= INT_MAX` is still valid,  should the for-loop not continue and also be infinite?

Comment: Please pronounce something reasonable then.

Comment: Undefined behavior is undefined. The result of executing a program with undefined behavior is an elephant being spawned in your bathroom.

Comment: @EOF: The question is well reasoned, and the only error is in the third sentence, that overflowing an `int` will produce some `int` value rather than being allowed to produce any behavior.

Comment: there is no INT_MAX+1 like there is no ∞+1. It starts from (int) -MAX.  https://os.mbed.com/handbook/C-Data-Types

Comment: @wired: OP means `INT_MAX`+1, that is, the mathematical integer that is one greater than `INT_MAX`, which does exist (in the sense that any abstract number exists). Observe the C standard itself uses similar language; `+` is defined to produce “the sum of the operands,” even though no such sum exists in the presence of overflow. The verbiage stating what happens for overflow is separate, not even in the same clause. OP does the same thing in discussing how `i++` would assume the sum of `INT_MAX` and 1, and separately discusses what happens in the presence of this overflow.

Comment: It seems my question was poorly expressed. My question was about why the undefined behavior of overflow allows the compiler to do optimization rather than on the the undefined behavior itself.

Comment: @Saibō: The question was expressed fine. The votes down are inappropriate.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> … then i will be assigned `INT_MAX+1`, which would overflow to an undefined value such as between 0 and INT_MAX.

No, that is not correct. That is written as if the rule were:

- If `++i` overflows, then `i` will be given some `int` value, although it is not specified which one.

However, the rule is:

- If `++i` overflows, the entire behavior of the program is undefined by the C standard.

That is, if `++i` overflows, the C standard allows any of these things to happen:

- `i` stays at `INT_MAX`.
- `i` changes to `INT_MIN`.
- `i` changes to zero.
- `i` changes to 37.
- The processor generates a trap, and the operating system terminates your process.
- Some other variable changes value.
- Program control jumps out of the loop, as if it had ended normally.
- Anything.

Now consider this assumption used in optimization by the compiler:

> … the compiler can assume that the loop will iterate exactly N+1 times…

If `++i` can only set `i` to some `int` value, then the loop will not terminate, as you conclude. On the other hand, if the compiler generates code that assumes the loop will iterate exactly N+1 times, then something else will happen in the case when `++i` overflows. Exactly what happens depends on the contents of the loop and what the compiler does with them. But it does not matter what: Generating this code is allowed by the C standard because **whatever** happens when `++i` overflows is allowed by the C standard.

Answer (score 2):

Lets consider an actual case:

```
#include <limits.h>
#include <stdio.h>

unsigned long long test_int(unsigned long long L, int N) {
    for (int i = 0; i <= N; ++i) {
        L++;
    return L;
}

unsigned long long test_unsigned(unsigned long long L, unsigned N) {
    for (unsigned i = 0; i <= N; ++i) {
        L++;
    return L;
}

int main() {
    fprintf(stderr, "int: %llu\n", test_int(0, INT_MAX));
    fprintf(stderr, "unsigned: %llu\n", test_unsigned(0, UINT_MAX));
    return 0;
}
```

The point of the blog article is the of possible behavior of the compiler for the above code:

- for `test_int()` the compiler can determine that for argument values from `INT_MIN` to `-1`, the function should return `L` unchanged, for values between `0` and `INT_MAX-1`, the return value should be `L + N + 1` and for `INT_MAX` the behavior is undefined, so returning `L + N + 1` is OK too, hence the code can be simplified as

  ```
    unsigned long long test_int(unsigned long long L, int N) {
        if (N >= 0)
            L += N + 1;
        return L;
    }
  ```
- for `test_unsigned()`, the same analysis yields: for argument values below `UINT_MAX`, the return value is `L + N + 1` and for `UINT_MAX` there is an infinite loop:

  ```
    unsigned long long test_unsigned(unsigned long long L, unsigned N) {
        if (N != UINT_MAX)
            return L + N + 1;
        for (;;);
    }
  ```

As can be seen on https://godbolt.org/z/abafdE8P4 both gcc and clang perform this optimisation for `test_int`, taking advantage of undefined behavior on overflow but generate iterative code for `test_unsigned`.

Answer (score 0):

Signed integer overflow invokes the Undefined Behaviour. Programmer cannot assume that a portable program will behave the particular way.

On the other hand, a program compiled for the particular platform using particular version of the compiler and using the same versions of the libraries will behave deterministic way. But you do not know if any of those change (ie. compiler, compiler version etc etc) that the behaviour will remain the same.

So your assumptions can be valid for the particular build and execution environment, but are invalid in general.